# Robust type caster for STL-vector-like classes

Tags: pybind11

I have a class that is quite similar to an STL-vector (the differences are not important for the pybind11 type caster, so I will ignore them here). I have written a type caster for this class. A minimal working example of my code is given below. An example showing the problem is included below the code.

The problem is that my caster is quite limited (because I have used `py::array_t`). In principle the interface does accept tuples, lists, and numpy-arrays. However, when I overload based on typename, the interface fails for inputted tuples and lists (simply the first overload is selected even though it is the incorrect type).

My question is: *How can I make the type caster more robust? Is there an effective way to re-use as much as possible existing type casters for STL-vector-like classes?*

#### C++ code (including pybind11 interface)

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
#include <pybind11/stl.h>
#include <pybind11/numpy.h>

namespace py = pybind11;

// class definition
// ----------------

template<typename T>
class Vector
{
private:

  std::vector<T> mData;

public:

  Vector(){};
  Vector(size_t N) { mData.resize(N); };

  auto   data ()       { return mData.data (); };
  auto   data () const { return mData.data (); };
  auto   begin()       { return mData.begin(); };
  auto   begin() const { return mData.begin(); };
  auto   end  ()       { return mData.end  (); };
  auto   end  () const { return mData.end  (); };
  size_t size () const { return mData.size (); };

  std::vector<size_t> shape()   const { return std::vector<size_t>(1, mData.size()); }
  std::vector<size_t> strides() const { return std::vector<size_t>(1, sizeof(T)   ); }

  template<typename It> static Vector<T> Copy(It first, It last) {
    Vector out(last-first);
    std::copy(first, last, out.begin());
    return out;
  }
};

// C++ functions: overload based on type
// -------------------------------------

Vector<int>    foo(const Vector<int>    &A){ std::cout << "int"    << std::endl; return A; }
Vector<double> foo(const Vector<double> &A){ std::cout << "double" << std::endl; return A; }

// pybind11 type caster
// --------------------

namespace pybind11 {
namespace detail {

template<typename T> struct type_caster<Vector<T>>
{
public:

  PYBIND11_TYPE_CASTER(Vector<T>, _("Vector<T>"));

  bool load(py::handle src, bool convert)
  {
    if ( !convert && !py::array_t<T>::check_(src) ) return false;

    auto buf = py::array_t<T, py::array::c_style | py::array::forcecast>::ensure(src);
    if ( !buf ) return false;

    auto rank = buf.ndim();
    if ( rank != 1 ) return false;

    value = Vector<T>::Copy(buf.data(), buf.data()+buf.size());

    return true;
  }

  static py::handle cast(const Vector<T>& src, py::return_value_policy policy, py::handle parent)
  {
    py::array a(std::move(src.shape()), std::move(src.strides()), src.data());

    return a.release();
  }
};

}} // namespace pybind11::detail

// Python interface
// ----------------

PYBIND11_MODULE(example,m)
{
  m.doc() = "pybind11 example plugin";

  m.def("foo", py::overload_cast<const Vector<int   > &>(&foo));
  m.def("foo", py::overload_cast<const Vector<double> &>(&foo));
}
```

#### Example

```python
import numpy as np
import example

print(example.foo((1,2,3)))
print(example.foo((1.5,2.5,3.5)))

print(example.foo(np.array([1,2,3])))
print(example.foo(np.array([1.5,2.5,3.5])))
```

Output:

```
int
[1 2 3]
int
[1 2 3]
int
[1 2 3]
double
[1.5 2.5 3.5]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A very easy solution is to specialise `pybind11::detail::list_caster`. The type caster now becomes as easy as

```cpp
namespace pybind11 {
namespace detail {

template <typename Type> struct type_caster<Vector<Type>> : list_caster<Vector<Type>, Type> { };

}} // namespace pybind11::detail
```

Note that this does require `Vector` to have the methods:

- `clear()`
- `push_back(const Type &value)`
- `reserve(size_t n)` (seems optional in testing)

---

#### Complete example

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
#include <pybind11/stl.h>
#include <pybind11/numpy.h>

namespace py = pybind11;

// class definition
// ----------------

template<typename T>
class Vector
{
private:

  std::vector<T> mData;

public:

  Vector(){};
  Vector(size_t N) { mData.resize(N); };

  auto   data ()       { return mData.data (); };
  auto   data () const { return mData.data (); };
  auto   begin()       { return mData.begin(); };
  auto   begin() const { return mData.begin(); };
  auto   end  ()       { return mData.end  (); };
  auto   end  () const { return mData.end  (); };
  size_t size () const { return mData.size (); };

  void push_back(const T &value) { mData.push_back(value); }
  void clear() { mData.clear(); }
  void reserve(size_t n) { mData.reserve(n); }

  std::vector<size_t> shape()   const { return std::vector<size_t>(1, mData.size()); }
  std::vector<size_t> strides() const { return std::vector<size_t>(1, sizeof(T)   ); }

  template<typename It> static Vector<T> Copy(It first, It last) {
    printf("Vector<T>::Copy %s\n", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    Vector out(last-first);
    std::copy(first, last, out.begin());
    return out;
  }
};

// C++ functions: overload based on type
// -------------------------------------

Vector<int>    foo(const Vector<int>    &A){ std::cout << "int"    << std::endl; return A; }
Vector<double> foo(const Vector<double> &A){ std::cout << "double" << std::endl; return A; }

// pybind11 type caster
// --------------------

    namespace pybind11 {
    namespace detail {

    template <typename Type> struct type_caster<Vector<Type>> : list_caster<Vector<Type>, Type> { };

    }} // namespace pybind11::detail

// Python interface
// ----------------

PYBIND11_MODULE(example,m)
{
  m.doc() = "pybind11 example plugin";

  m.def("foo", py::overload_cast<const Vector<double> &>(&foo));
  m.def("foo", py::overload_cast<const Vector<int   > &>(&foo));

}
```